# Looking for 'onChange' but using 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently working on a React project.

I don't want to add my 'onChange' in each button inside the html object like this:
`<input type='text' onChange={myFunction} />`

I want to add it in the JS code like this:
`document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('eventName', myFunction);`

The problem is that my first though that the `change` event was the equivalent `onChange` inside the HTML, but I was wrong.
Actually, the `change` is working like a `onBlur` event but triggered only when the field got modified.

I also tried the `keypress` event like this:
`document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('eventName', myFunction);`
But when I try to get the value with `event.target.value`, it gives me the value before input.

This problem is only related to `textarea` and `input type='text'`. `select`, `input type='date'` and other object on which we can click are not affected by this problem.

Is there a simple event working as the `onChange` inside the HTML ?

Comment: _"The problem is that my first though that the change event was the equivalent onChange"_ in plain HTML/JavaScript it is, inline `onChange` and JS `addEventListener` show no difference in behaviour between methods. _"I'm currently working on a React project."_ This is a throw away line in your question but is the root of the discrepancy. Add an [mcve] so that you can show us the difference.

Comment: If you're using React you should probably stick with the conventions an use `onChange={myFunction}`. Learn , embrace and leverage React's  own conventions and you porobably won't find yourself fighting against React further down the line. Give us a realistic example and there may be an even better way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event):

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log('Value is now: ' + this.value)
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Perfect, it was exactly what I was looking for! I accept your answer asap.

Comment: I think the inclusion of React in the question really means that they probably shouldn't be using `addEventListener` at all.